# Grabbing full file path of a zipped geodatabase using Python

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, directory, zip

I am attempting to grab the file path of a file within a zipped file. For example, I have this file: "E:\API_creation\upload\TestingData.zip\TestingData.gdb". I would like to create a python script that will grab the file path "E:\API_creation\upload\TestingData.zip." However, when I run the following script, I am left with the following output: "E:\API_creation\upload\TestingData.gdb." It is missing the zip folder in the file path name for some reason.

```
gdbfiles = []
shpfiles = []
csvfiles = []
jsonfiles = []
zipfiles = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk (folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".zip"):
            zipfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        elif file.endswith(".csv"):
            csvfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        elif file.endswith(".json"):
            jsonfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        else:
            pass
#find zipped gdb files
gdb_dirs = []  
for i in zipfiles:
    zip_f = ZipFile(i)
    for f in zip_f.namelist():
        zinfo = zip_f.getinfo(f)
        if zinfo.is_dir():
            r_dir = f.split('/')
            r_dir = r_dir[0]
            if r_dir not in gdb_dirs:
                gdb_dirs.append(r_dir)

for i in gdb_dirs:
    if i.endswith(".gdb"):
        gdbfiles.append(os.path.join(root, i))
    else:
        pass
print(gdbfiles)
```

Comment: Well for one thing, `root` is treated as the GDB's directory near the end but `root` is just left over as the last subdirectory that `os.walk` returned.  This isn't really a GIS question, though, you just need to step through it in a debugger

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix it? I've already spent a lot of time debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong for identifying gdbs within the zip.  Look at `zip_f.namelist()` to see why.  You just need to concatenate the zip path with any zip member names that end with `.gdb/`

```py
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile

folder = r'C:\example'

gdbfiles = []
shpfiles = []
csvfiles = []
jsonfiles = []
zipfiles = []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".zip"):
            zipfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        elif file.endswith(".csv"):
            csvfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))
        elif file.endswith(".json"):
            jsonfiles.append(os.path.join(root, file))


#find zipped gdb files
for zip_path in zipfiles:
    zip_f = ZipFile(zip_path)
    for name in zip_f.namelist():
        if name.endswith('.gdb/'):
            gdbfiles.append(os.path.join(zip_path, name))

print(gdbfiles)
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!